# Rails.vim plugin, does it have any fancy migration support?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, rails.vim

I am hoping rails.vim has some migration support.

I'm looking for something like:  generate migration and jump to that file, and then a way to fire the migration.

Does this exist or am I dreaming? :)

Comment: Could you accept one of the answers ;) ?

Answer (score 13):

You definitely can!

As mentioned, you can run the following to generate a migration:

```
:Rgenerate migration migration_name ...
```

Then this will switch to the latest migration:

```
:Rmigration
```

And then finally:

```
:Rake db:migrate
```

will actually migrate it for you.

Also I shouldn't forget to add that running

```
:Rinvert
```

in a migration file, will try to create the down portion of your migration (or visa versa).

Answer (score 3):

With regard to running a migration:

When in migration file, e.g. `123456789_my_migration.rb`:

- `:Rake` will call `rake db:migrate VERSION=123456789`.

  *Note the `.` preceeding `Rake` in the following (this sends the line number to the command):*
- `:.Rake` on line **1**, or inside the `down` method, will call
  `rake db:migrate:down VERSION=123456789`.
- `:.Rake` on the **last** line, or inside the `up` method, will call
  `rake db:migrate:up VERSION=123456789`.
- `:.Rake` anywhere else in the file will call
  `rake db:migrate:down db:migrate:up VERSION=123456789`.

I don't know of any documentation for this, I figured it out from looking at [the appropriate part of rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails/blob/8412c9b9fef6225696be6c4a97e58a7eb1bbbf1a/autoload/rails.vim#L1267).

Answer (score 0):

Jeje definitaly not dreaming. I should warn you that is a bit slow.

To generate the migration

```
:Rgenerate migration migration_name table_attributes
```

To run rake db:migrate

```
:Rake db:migrate
```

You can run an specific migration passing along VERSION="xxx". For more information on how to do this, you can go to `:help rails-rake`